# Hey guys i'm new to web design, need some advices about this

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Can't figure out how to align this item like on photo

Making a web design from my prototype, but stacked here, tried many variations, couldn't figure out, this is what I've got.

If you can help somehow, it is would great.[this is how it should look like[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJkfI.png).

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-light">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1 class="text-center pqetitle">¿Por qué elegirnos?</h1>
            <h3 class="text-center pqetxt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
           <h1 class="text-left pqesbtitle">Garantizar </h1>

           <img class="text-right pqeicn" src="./img/quienes_somos/Garantizar_icon.png" alt="">

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
           <h1 class="text-left pqesbtitle">Soporte</h1>

           <img class="text-right pqeicn" src="./img/quienes_somos/Soporte_Tecnico_icon.png" alt="">

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <img class="pqeimg"src="./img/quienes_somos/pic_por_que_elegirnos.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
           <h1 class="text-left pqesbtitle">Instalación</h1>

           <img class="text-right pqeicn" src="./img/quienes_somos/Instalacion_icon.png" alt="">

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
           <h1 class="text-left pqesbtitle">Innovaciones</h1>

           <img class="text-right pqeicn" src="./img/quienes_somos/Innovations_icon.png" alt="">

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you have any CSS?

Comment: Have no clue what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Bootstrap.

Have a look, maybe this is what you are looking for :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="text-align: center;">
          <h1 class="text-center pqetitle">¿Por qué elegirnos?</h1>
          <h3 class="text-center pqetxt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="mini-box">

                <h1 class="text-left pqesbtitle">Garantizar </h1>

                <img class="text-right pqeicn" src="./img/quienes_somos/Garantizar_icon.png" alt="">

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="mini-box">
                <h1 class="text-left pqesbtitle">Soporte</h1>

                <img class="text-right pqeicn" src="./img/quienes_somos/Soporte_Tecnico_icon.png" alt="">

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="big-box text-center">
            <img class="pqeimg" src="./img/quienes_somos/pic_por_que_elegirnos.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="mini-box">

                <h1 class="text-left pqesbtitle">Instalación</h1>

                <img class="text-right pqeicn" src="./img/quienes_somos/Instalacion_icon.png" alt="">

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="mini-box">
                <h1 class="text-left pqesbtitle">Innovaciones</h1>

                <img class="text-right pqeicn" src="./img/quienes_somos/Innovations_icon.png" alt="">

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yup, i do use bootstrap, unfortunately did not worked, you can check out the description of my problem, there is a photo how it should look like(

Comment: What did not work ?
When you run the snipped you should see the arrangement like in your picture.
Next steps would be inserting the images.

Comment: This is what happens when you give guess answers @benvoe Don't do that when you aren't sure what the question is or the details are. SO is about giving solid answers not guesses.